# libgdx: rendering a model w/ texture, looks washed out

Tags: opengl, libgdx, textures, lighting

I'm working with LibGDX and Blender on a sort of beginner's exercise to render a 3d model.

I've created a six-sided dice, uvunwrapped it and created a png file uvmap. In Blender it looks fine. However, in the game window it appears sort of greyed out.

I've tried a few different light configurations but no luck. Could this be a material issue? Any suggestions?

Screenshots and code below. Thanks!

[image: blender 3d view]
[image]

```
public class ShipRenderer implements ApplicationListener {
public Environment environment;
public PerspectiveCamera cam;
public CameraInputController camController;
public ModelBatch modelBatch;
public Model model;
public ModelInstance instance;

Color lightColor;
PointLight light;

float DISTANCE = 40f;

@Override
public void create() {
    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
    environment = new Environment();
    environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1.0f));

    cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.position.set(DISTANCE, DISTANCE, DISTANCE);
    cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
    cam.near = 1f;
    cam.far = 150f;
    cam.update();

    UBJsonReader jsonReader = new UBJsonReader();
    G3dModelLoader loader = new G3dModelLoader(jsonReader);
    model = loader.loadModel(Gdx.files.internal("dice/dice.g3db"));
    instance = new ModelInstance(model);

    camController = new CameraInputController(cam);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(camController);
}

@Override
public void render() {
    camController.update();

    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    modelBatch.begin(cam);
    modelBatch.render(instance, environment);
    modelBatch.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turns out my Blender model was 'glowing', in other words it was emitting light. The blender 3dView didn't show this though.

I exported the blender file as a G3DJ file to be able to see the contents. From there we saw the 'emissive' property was nonzero. Zeroed that out and looks correct now. Here it is with a white background.

Many thanks to the LibGDX Discord channel!

[image]

Comment: Please can you explain how you zeroed this out exactly? I am stuck with the same issue. I also can't get Will Davies modified fbx-conv.exe to work for some reason. Thank you.

Comment: @hamham, you need to do two things: 1) export the fbx to the json format so you can modify the values manually, and 2) open the file, find the emissive value section and change it to zero.

Comment: Thanks @ether_joe, I couldn't figure out how to export the fbx as a json, but I figured out how to remove the emissive attribute from the materials after loading. I will add this solution as an answer as it may be helpful for others.

Comment: @hamham looks like the syntax is, `fbx-conv -f -o G3DJ file.fbx` https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Importing-Blender-models-in-LibGDX .

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has this issue, here is a solution to remove the emissive material properties after loading the model. I personally had trouble exporting the fbx to json, so this is the only way that worked for me.

```
private void removeEmissiveAttributes(Model model){
    for(Material m : model.materials){
        m.remove(ColorAttribute.Emissive);
    }
}
```